# How do I get a bot to mention someone?

Tags: python, discord.py

I've been trying to make my bot mention someone for a command for a while, I was looking around Google and other websites and most of them where specific people like using <@(User ID)> but I want to make it mention whoever, like, when I use a command like "?hit" I would like it to say "(bot pings who used the command) punches (person pinged in command)
(Random message idk)"

I can't find a website or video of how to do it I need a little help.

Comment: You need to decompose the problem into sub-problems. Figure out how to get a list of all users in the channel, Figure out how to pick a random entry from a list. Figure out how to mention a known user. Combine the above and you'll have a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every Member object is mentionable (using the `mention` function), read up on the docs [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=mention#discord.Member.mention). Using that, we can create a command which takes in a `member` to `hit`. Then, we can ping the `ctx.author` and `member` using the function `mention`. It would look something like:

```
@client.command()
async def hit(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} punches {member.mention}")
```

Output:

[image: l]

Answer (score 0):

I don't mean to be rude but this question was easily answered by looking at the [discord API docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html), as it explains everything in the API and what it does. My solution is below. You didn't provide any code or problem you've had with code so this is all I can do.

```
@client.command() # here, we make the client command.
async def hit(ctx, member : discord.Member): # we are making the function that actually hits the person here.
    await ctx.send(f'{ctx.message.author.mention} hits {member.mention}.') # here, we send the message that pings both the user who triggered the command, and the person who the you want to ping.
```

If you wanted to have it select from a list, for example, here's how that'd work.

```
@client.command()
async def hit(ctx, member : discord.Member):

    # this is a list of random responses that could happen.
    hit_responses = [f'{ctx.message.author.mention} hits {member.mention}.',
    f'{ctx.message.author.mention} swings and hits {member.mention}.',
    f'{ctx.message.author.mention} slaps {member.mention} across the face.'] 

    hit_message = random.choice(hit_respones) # this chooses a random response.

    await ctx.send(hit_message) # this sends the random response
```

An example output would be as follows:

```
@goose.mp4 slaps @user across the face.
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with asking them to provide code :) But great for helping them I suppose!